# wcf webservice call with postman

Tags: java, android, angular, soapui, postman

hi guys i'am requesting soap wcf webService with postman and i am getting this error also my co-workers get response 200 with angular and .Net platform , 
PS: i want to implement this request in android studio so i need to see response first

this is my request

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <tem:QueryMessage>
        <tem:messageSet>
            <san:ActionId>?</san:ActionId>
            <san:Ip>::1</san:Ip>

            <san:Parameters>
                  <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Username</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>tipex</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>
                <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Password</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>123456</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>
            </san:Parameters>

            <san:Title>Authenticate</san:Title>
            <san:Token>?</san:Token>
            <san:Username>tipex</san:Username>
        </tem:messageSet>
    </tem:QueryMessage>
</x:Body>
```

and this is my response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:messageSet. The InnerException message was 'Element Value from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
```

this is .NET request

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new ServiceHelper();
        var msg = new IrptServiceReference.Message();
        msg.Username = textBox1.Text;
        msg.Title = "Authenticate";
        msg.Parameters = new List<IrptServiceReference.Parameter>();
        msg.Ip = "::1";
        msg.Parameters.Add(new IrptServiceReference.Parameter { Name = "Password", Value = textBox2.Text });
        msg.Parameters.Add(new IrptServiceReference.Parameter { Name = "Username", Value = textBox1.Text });
        var dt = service.MessageExchange(msg);
        if (dt == null) return;
        var token = dt[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = token;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing `x:Envelope` tag is missing

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <tem:QueryMessage>
        <tem:messageSet>
            <san:ActionId>?</san:ActionId>
            <san:Ip>::1</san:Ip>

            <san:Parameters>
                  <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Username</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>tipex</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>
                <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Password</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>123456</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>
            </san:Parameters>

            <san:Title>Authenticate</san:Title>
            <san:Token>?</san:Token>
            <san:Username>tipex</san:Username>
        </tem:messageSet>
    </tem:QueryMessage>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Comment: i have added .net request

Comment: any idea?? i'm confused

Comment: send me sample documentation url